# Nginx cannot serve Rails files in Unicorn + Vagrant setup

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nginx, unicorn

I'm trying to setup a local Rails 3.2 dev environment in Vagrant VM running Ubuntu 12.04 with Unicorn + Nginx. I installed nginx with a softlink as follows:

```
sudo apt-get install nginx
Create symlink for nginx conf file for dactarkhoj
cd /etc/nginx/sites-enabled
sudo ln -s /vagrant/config/nginx.conf dactarkhoj.conf
sudo service nginx start
```

The Unicorn is also setup and I started it using

```
unicorn_rails  -c /vagrant/config/unicorn.rb -D
```

Now for some reason when I open up the browser I only get the 'Welcome to nginx' message instead of the rails app. What could be the possible pitfalls that caused this?

The nginx.conf file is

```
upstream unicorn {
  server unix:/tmp/unicorn.dactarkhoj.sock fail_timeout=0;
}

server {
  listen 80 default;
  root /vagrant/public;
  try_files $uri/index.html $uri @unicorn;
  location @unicorn {
    proxy_pass http://unicorn;
  }

  error_page 500 502 503 504 /500.html;
}
```

The Unicorn conf file is

```
worker_processes 4

rails_root = File.expand_path('../..', __FILE__)
working_directory rails_root

listen '/tmp/unicorn.dactarkhoj.sock'

pid File.expand_path('tmp/pids/unicorn.pid', ENV['RAILS_ROOT'])

# combine REE with "preload_app true" for memory savings
# http://rubyenterpriseedition.com/faq.html#adapt_apps_for_cow
preload_app true

# Set the path of the log files inside the log folder of the testapp
stderr_path "/vagrant/log/unicorn.stderr.log"
stdout_path "/vagrant/log/unicorn.stdout.log"

before_fork do |server, worker|
  defined?(ActiveRecord::Base) and ActiveRecord::Base.connection.disconnect!

  old_pid = "#{ server.config[:pid] }.oldbin"
  unless old_pid == server.pid
    begin
      Process.kill :QUIT, File.read(old_pid).to_i
    rescue Errno::ENOENT, Errno::ESRCH
    end
  end
end

after_fork do |server, worker|
  defined?(ActiveRecord::Base) and ActiveRecord::Base.establish_connection
end
```

Comment: Are you using 3.2, ok? Are you using asset pipeline or not?

Comment: @RodrigoOliveira yes it is enabled. just left it at the default settings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you said, here's your setup:

```
Create symlink for nginx conf file for dactarkhoj
cd /etc/nginx/sites-enabled
sudo ln -s /vagrant/config/nginx.conf dactarkhoj.conf
sudo service nginx start
```

I think that you should copy **dactarkhoj.conf** to **/etc/nginx/sites-enabled/default** and override it.